# How can I track the "Traffic Sources" of "Unique Visitors" by Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, statistics, matomo

Now I can only see the "Traffic Sources" of "Visits".  But what I would like to know is  the number of "Unique Visitors" from each referrals. But when I go to "Traffic Sources" -"Referrals" from the left side menu bar it only shows the number of  "Visits"  Any idea? Or if google analytics doesn't provide this are there other similar tools for it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same screen shows you the `% New Visits` which gives you an indication of how many of the total visits are unique. You can also click `secondary dimension` and add `visitor type` which will show you new vs returning, again giving you a metric to judge uniques.

Comment: Thanks I hadn't realized that it can be calculated by %New Vsitis. However looks like this doesn't work for me. On my site the visitors are granted a member role automatically on their registration. I have set this member role as custom variable (scope-user). My goal is to find out the number of the visitor who registered on my site per referral. I can roughly count it by using %New Visits but the problem is for example when a visitor registers on the second or third visit. Sorry I hadn't mentioned this above just to make the question simpler and just now I realized this problem. Any idea?

Comment: @chiba I think you're going to need custom software to do this, but it might be achievable with goal tracking - I would suggest you do some research in that direction

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. And can you please kidly let me know what "goal tracking" means is it a name of software or something?

Comment: http://analytics.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/new-google-analytics-events-goals.html